# How to access a ZFS zvol SNAPSHOT block device?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, zfs, snapshot

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 box running ZFS.    I'm using the zfs-auto-snapshot script to create regular snapshots.   Included in my ZFS setup is a ZVOL block device.    I want to access (read-only) a snapshot of this ZVOL, but I'm unable to find the resource.

When I do a zfs list -t snapshot, I see a number of snapshots of this block device like

> zfspool/folio_drbd@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2017-12-01-1711      2.59G
>   -   178G  - zfspool/folio_drbd@zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2017-12-08-1511       31.3G      -   207G  - zfspool/folio_drbd@zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2017-12-22-1511       1.97G
>   -   194G  - zfspool/folio_drbd@zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2017-12-29-1511        908M      -   197G  -

These do not appear in /zfspool/.zfs/snapshot/zfs-auto-snap-*   - How can I access the ZVOL snapshot ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snapshots of zvols are not automatically displayed inside the file system hierarchy like file system snapshots are (because they can contain any other file system), but you can `mount` and access them at your chosen destination (again, depending on the content of the zvol). If mounting fails, you may try to first clone and then mount the clone, as detailed in [this mailing list post](http://list.zfsonlinux.org/pipermail/zfs-discuss/2016-September/026251.html):

> did you run `dmesg | tail`? My GUESS is that the fs needs journal reply,
>   which fails because snapshots are immutable. Mounting the clone would fix
>   this issue.
>
> Try cloning it first, e.g. `zfs clone tank/vmdk1@ckpnt2 tank/vmdk1-ckpnt2-clone`,
>   then `mount /dev/zvol/tank/vmdk1-ckpnt2-clone /mnt/snap1`

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but ...

I just stumbled across the same problem. Slightly different from the OP, I didn't expect my ZVOL snapshots in `/zfspool/.zfs`, but somewhere in the `/dev` tree.

Originally, I couldn't find them there. After reading `man zfs`, the subject became clear. They are hidden by default, but we can easily make them visible by setting the `snapdev` property accordingly. In my case, I have a ZVOL `rpool/vm-temp`. To make its snapshots visible, I just had to do

```
zfs set snapdev=visible rpool/vm-temp
```

However, I reverted this setting, because I have several thousands of snapshots which are visible in at least two places: In numbered notation directly in `/dev` (example: `/dev/zd9984p1`), and with symbolic names in `/dev/zvol/rpool/` (example: `/dev/zvol/rpool/vm-temp@Y-2020-06-29-13-44-12-part1`), where the latter are just symbolic links to the former.

As one may imagine, several thousands of snapshot devices directly in `/dev` make `/dev` somehow unusable, so I make the ZVOL snapshot devices visible only temporarily in case of problems and leave them hidden otherwise.

A very interesting additional aspect:

If you have a ZVOL which acts as (let's say) disk for a VM, you likely have several partitions in it. If there are `N` partitions, you will get `N+1` additional snapshot devices with each snapshot, because the ZVOL itself is treated as disk device, and the partitions are recognized as, well, partitions. Hence, as it would be the case with a bare metal disk with multiple partitions, you get `1 + number of partitions` new block devices per ZVOL snapshot.

You can see this from my example above: I have `vm-temp@Y-2020-06-29-13-44-12-part1`, but also a device with `-part2` instead of `-part1` (because I have two partitions in this ZVOL), plus one device without the trailing `-part...` at all, representing the ZVOL itself.

So the answer to the question is:

You can access the snapshots using the devices in `/dev/zvol/zfspool` or those in `/dev`, provided you have made them visible by setting the `snapdev` property for the ZVOL in question to `visible`.

Unfortunately, you can actually use these snapshot devices only if they are visible, so the way shown in the other answer (clone a snapshot, use the clone) might be the better way, depending on the number of snapshots you have and depending on whether you can or cannot live with them cluttering the `/dev` directory. Cloning a snapshot works regardless of whether or not the snapshot device is visible in the `/dev` tree.

So the other answer so far is correct. I just wanted to add an explanation of how you actually can show these devices, enabling you to use them directly without having to clone them.

Comment: From what I understand, this actually answers OP problem. OP just didn't realize that it supposed to be under /dev/zvol. But of course cloning would be a standard way to access a particular snapshot as read only (not all the thousands of them). However if I don't have many of them your answer of snapdev is also very useful!